# Operating System Basics

Tags: process, operating-system

I am reading process management,and I have a few doubts-

- What is meant by an I/o request,for E.g.-A process is executing and
  hence it is in running state,it is in waiting state if it is waiting
  for the completion of an **I/O request**.I am not getting by what is meant by an **I/O request**,Can you
  please give an example to elaborate.
- Another doubt is -Lets say that a process is executing and suddenly
  an interrupt occurs,then the process stops its execution and will be
  put in the ready state,is it possible that some other process began
  its execution while the interrupt is also being processed?

Comment: sounds like you need help with your homework!

Comment: @Shaunak-Its not a homework,

Answer (score 3):

**Regarding the first question:**

A simple way to think about it...
Your computer has lots of components. CPU, Hard Drive, network card, sound card, gpu, etc. All those work in parallel and independent of each other. They are also generally slower than the CPU.
This means that whenever a process makes a call that down the line (on the OS side) ends up communicating with an external device, there is no point for the OS to be stuck waiting for the result since the time it takes for that operation to complete is probably an eternity (in the CPU view point of things).
So, the OS fires up whatever communication the process requested (call it IO request), flags the process as waiting for IO, and switches execution to another process so the CPU can do something useful instead of sitting around blocked waiting for the IO request to complete.
When the external device finishes whatever operation was requested, it generates an interrupt, so the OS is informed the work is done, and it can then flag the blocked process as ready again.

This is all a very simplified view of course, but that's the main idea. It allows the CPU to do useful work instead of waiting for IO requests to complete.

**Regarding the second question:**

It's tricky, even for single CPU machines, and depends on how the OS handles interrupts.
For code simplicity, a simple OS might for example, whenever an interrupt happens process the interrupt in one go, then resume whatever process it decides it's appropriate whenever the interrupt handling is done. So in this case, no other process would run until the interrupt handling is complete.

In practice, things get a bit more complicated for performance and latency reasons.
If you think about an interrupt lifetime as just another task for the CPU (From when the interrupt starts to the point the OS considers that handling complete), you can effectively code the interrupt handling to run in parallel with other things.
Just think of the interrupt as notification for the OS to start another task (that interrupt handling). It grabs whatever context it needs at the point the interrupt started, then keeps processing that task in parallel with other processes.

Answer (score 1):

I/O request generally just means request to do either Input , Output or both. The exact meaning varies depending on your context like HTTP, Networks, Console Ops, or may be some process in the CPU.

**A process is waiting for IO:**  Say for example you were writing a program in C to accept user's name on command line, and then would like to print 'Hello User' back. Your code will go into waiting state until user enters their name and hits Enter.  This is a higher level example, but even on a very low level process executing in your computer's processor works on same basic principle

Can Processor work on other processes when current is interrupted and waiting on something? Yes! You better hope it does. Thats what scheduling algorithms and stacks are for.  However the real answer depending on what Architecture you are on, does it support parallel or serial processing etc.